# How can I find what is causing my memory allocation error when Valgrind gives me "the impossible happened"

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-management, malloc, valgrind

I am somewhat of a newbie programmer, doing a brief senior project for the last few weeks of high school. My program is essentially a bot designed to solve wordle. The last few days, I have been struggling with an elusive memory allocation error. I have only been coding in c++ for a couple of weeks, so I am not very used to errors of this nature. I have tried a myriad of printf statements, commenting out code, and gdb and valgrind, but am not sure how to interpret the error message the latter gave me. Here is my code (sorry if this is too long for a post, I am new to stackoverflow).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Guessdata{
        int average;
        char guess[5];
    };


struct {
        bool operator()(const Guessdata& a, const Guessdata& b) const { return a.average < b.average; }
    } customLess;


bool guessInList(string guess, string arr[], int num_words)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == guess)
        {
            cout << "The word '" << arr[i] << "' exists!" << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
void compareWords(char guess_arr[], char answer_arr[], int score[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        bool isScored = false;
        for(int j = 0; j <5; j++)
            if(guess_arr[i] == answer_arr[j])
            {
                if(i == j)
                {
                    score[i] = 2;
                    isScored = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!isScored)
                    {
                        score[i] = 1;
                        isScored = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        if(isScored == false)
        {
            score[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
void cleanChArray(char guess_array[], int score[], char remainingChArray[], char newChArray[], int remaining_count, int& added_counter)
{
    added_counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < remaining_count; i+=5)
    {
        bool keep_word = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            char guess_ch = guess_array[j];
            int score_j = score[j];
            if(score_j == 0)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    if(guess_ch == remainingChArray[i+k])
                    {
                        for(int e = 0; e < 5; e++)
                        {
                            if(guess_array[e] == remainingChArray[i+k] && e != k && score[e] != 0)
                            {
                                keep_word = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                keep_word = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(score_j == 2)
            {
                if(!(guess_ch == remainingChArray[i+j]))
                {
                    keep_word = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(score_j == 1)
            {
                int found = 0;
                for(int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
                {
                    if(guess_ch == remainingChArray[i+l] && j == l)
                    {
                        keep_word = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(guess_ch == remainingChArray[i+l] && j!=l)
                    {
                        found += 1;
                    }
                }
                if(found != 1)
                {
                    keep_word = false;
                }
            }
            if(!keep_word)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(keep_word)
        {
            for(int k = i; k < i+5; k++)
            {

                newChArray[added_counter] = remainingChArray[k];
                added_counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
int numberEliminated(char guess_arr[], char keyword_arr[], int score[], char remainingChArray[], char newChArray[], int remainingCount, int& added_counter)
{
    compareWords(guess_arr, keyword_arr, score);
    cleanChArray(guess_arr, score, remainingChArray, newChArray, remainingCount, added_counter);
    return(2309 - (added_counter)/5);
}
int averageEliminated(char guess_arr[], char remainingChArray[], int score[], char newChArray[], int remainingCount, int& added_counter)
{
    int num_elim = 0;
    int current_length = added_counter;
    for(int i = 0; i < remainingCount; i += 5)
    {
        char * keyword_array = new char[5];
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            keyword_array[j] = remainingChArray[i+j];
        }
        num_elim += numberEliminated(guess_arr, keyword_array, score, remainingChArray, newChArray, remainingCount, added_counter);
    }
    return num_elim/2309;
}

void makeGuess(char remainingChArray[], int score[], char newChArray[], int& remainingCount, int& added_counter, char final_guess[], int& num_attempts, Guessdata guess_dict[])
{
    printf("%i, %i, %i\n", remainingCount, added_counter, num_attempts);
    printf("coool\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < remainingCount/5; i ++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            guess_dict[i].guess[j] = remainingChArray[(5*i)+j];
            printf("%c", guess_dict[i].guess[j]);
        }
        guess_dict[i].average = averageEliminated(guess_dict[i].guess, remainingChArray, score, newChArray, remainingCount, added_counter);
        printf("%i  ", guess_dict[i].average);
    }
    /*if(num_attempts > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < remainingCount; i += 5)
        {
            printf("%i: ", guess_dict[i/5].average);
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                printf("%c", guess_dict[i/5].guess[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }*/
    printf("yee\n");
    if(remainingCount>5){

        std::sort(&guess_dict[0], &guess_dict[remainingCount/5], customLess);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        final_guess[i] = guess_dict[(remainingCount/5)-1].guess[i];
        printf("%c", final_guess[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    num_attempts += 1;
}

int main()
{
    const int num_words = 2309;
    string * ANSWERLIST = new string[num_words];
    char * chArray = new char[11545];
    char * officialGuess = new char[5];
    char * officialAnswer = new char[5];
    int count = 0;
    int attempts = 0;
    int * score_template = new int[5];
    int numberOfWords;
    int addCount = 0;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("ANSWERS.txt");
    if(!inputFile)
    {
        cout << "Error finding input file" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    while(!inputFile.eof())
    {
        inputFile >> ANSWERLIST[count];
        count++;
    }
    numberOfWords = count;
    int ch_count = 11545;
    int smaller_count = 5750;
    char * chAnswerList = new char[ch_count];
    char * smallerList = new char[smaller_count];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2309; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            chAnswerList[(5*i)+j] = ANSWERLIST[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 1150; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            smallerList[(i*5)+j] = ANSWERLIST[i][j];
        }
    }



    officialAnswer[0] = 'b';
    officialAnswer[1] = 'r';
    officialAnswer[2] = 'o';
    officialAnswer[3] = 'o';
    officialAnswer[4] = 'k';



    //REAL GAME LOGIC
    //FIRST GUESS
    printf("first guess: ");
    Guessdata * guess_dict = new Guessdata[ch_count/5];
    makeGuess(smallerList, score_template, chArray, smaller_count, addCount, officialGuess, attempts, guess_dict);
    compareWords(officialGuess, officialAnswer, score_template);
    bool match = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        if(score_template[i] != 2)
        {
            match = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(match)
    {
        printf("%i\n", attempts);
        return attempts;
    }
    cleanChArray(officialGuess, score_template, smallerList, chArray, ch_count, addCount);
    if(addCount == 0)
    {
        printf("fail");
        return 0;
    }
    char * secondList = new char[addCount/5];
    for(int i = 0; i < addCount; i++)
    {
        secondList[i] = chArray[i];
        printf("%c", secondList[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    ch_count = addCount;
    delete[] guess_dict;
    delete[] chAnswerList;
    printf("second guess: ");
    Guessdata * guess_dict2 = new Guessdata[ch_count/5];
    //SECOND GUESS
    makeGuess(secondList, score_template, chArray, ch_count, addCount, officialGuess, attempts, guess_dict2);
    compareWords(officialGuess, officialAnswer, score_template);
    match = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", score_template[i]);

        if(score_template[i] != 2)
        {
            match = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(match)
    {
        printf("%i\n", attempts);
        return attempts;
    }

    cleanChArray(officialGuess, score_template, secondList, chArray, ch_count, addCount);
    if(addCount == 0)
    {
        printf("fail");
        return 0;
    }
    char * thirdList = new char[addCount/5];
    for(int i = 0; i < addCount; i++)
    {
        thirdList[i] = chArray[i];
    }
    ch_count = addCount;

    delete[] secondList;
    delete[] guess_dict2;
    Guessdata * guess_dict3 = new Guessdata[ch_count/5];
    printf("third guess: ");
    //THIRD GUESS
    makeGuess(thirdList, score_template, chArray, ch_count, addCount, officialGuess, attempts, guess_dict3);
    compareWords(officialGuess, officialAnswer, score_template);
    match = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        
        if(score_template[i] != 2)
        {
            match = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(match)
    {
        printf("%i\n", attempts);
        return attempts;
    }

    cleanChArray(officialGuess, score_template, thirdList, chArray, ch_count, addCount);
    if(addCount == 0)
    {
        printf("fail");
        return 0;
    }
    char * fourthList = new char[addCount/5];
    for(int i = 0; i < addCount; i++)
    {
        fourthList[i] = chArray[i];
    }
    ch_count = addCount;

    delete[] thirdList;
    delete[] guess_dict3;
    Guessdata * guess_dict4 = new Guessdata[ch_count/5];

    //FOURTH GUESS
    makeGuess(fourthList, score_template, chArray, ch_count, addCount, officialGuess, attempts, guess_dict4);
    compareWords(officialGuess, officialAnswer, score_template);
    match = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(score_template[i] != 2)
        {
            match = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(match)
    {
        printf("%i\n", attempts);
        return attempts;
    }

    cleanChArray(officialGuess, score_template, fourthList, chArray, ch_count, addCount);
    if(addCount == 0)
    {
        printf("fail");
        return 0;
    }
    char * fifthList = new char[addCount/5];
    for(int i = 0; i < addCount; i++)
    {
        fifthList[i] = chArray[i];
    }
    ch_count = addCount;

    delete[] fourthList;
    delete[] guess_dict4;
    Guessdata * guess_dict5 = new Guessdata[ch_count/5];

    //FIFTH GUESS
    makeGuess(fifthList, score_template, chArray, ch_count, addCount, officialGuess, attempts, guess_dict5);
    compareWords(officialGuess, officialAnswer, score_template);
    match = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        if(score_template[i] != 2)
        {
            match = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(match)
    {
        printf("%i\n", attempts);
        return attempts;
    }

    cleanChArray(officialGuess, score_template, fifthList, chArray, ch_count, addCount);
    if(addCount == 0)
    {
        printf("fail");
        return 0;
    }
    char * sixthList = new char[addCount/5];
    for(int i = 0; i < addCount; i++)
    {
        sixthList[i] = chArray[i];
    }
    ch_count = addCount;

    delete[] fifthList;
    delete[] guess_dict5;
    Guessdata * guess_dict6 = new Guessdata[ch_count/5];

    //SIXTH GUESS
    makeGuess(fifthList, score_template, chArray, ch_count, addCount, officialGuess, attempts, guess_dict6);
    compareWords(officialGuess, officialAnswer, score_template);
    match = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(score_template[i] != 2)
        {
            match = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(match)
    {
        printf("%i\n", attempts);
        return attempts;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FAIL\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am fairly certain somewhere along the way I am writing beyond the memory allocated to a certain array or something, but cannot for the life of me figure out where. I have run Valgrind on this script and gotten the following output:

```
==386== Invalid read of size 1
==386==    at 0x109CEA: cleanChArray(char*, int*, char*, char*, int, int&) (methods.cpp:75)
==386==    by 0x10A3FC: main (methods.cpp:277)
==386==  Address 0x4dc5206 is 0 bytes after a block of size 5,750 alloc'd
==386==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==386==    by 0x10A261: main (methods.cpp:229)
==386==
==386== Invalid read of size 1
==386==    at 0x109D0F: cleanChArray(char*, int*, char*, char*, int, int&) (methods.cpp:95)
==386==    by 0x10A3FC: main (methods.cpp:277)
==386==  Address 0x4dc5208 is 2 bytes after a block of size 5,750 alloc'd
==386==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==386==    by 0x10A261: main (methods.cpp:229)
==386==
==386== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==386==    at 0x109CF2: cleanChArray(char*, int*, char*, char*, int, int&) (methods.cpp:75)
==386==    by 0x10A3FC: main (methods.cpp:277)
==386==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==386==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==386==    by 0x4AD6E83: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==386==    by 0x4AE704F: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==386==    by 0x4AE60AF: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:745)
==386==    by 0x4AE4834: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1244)
==386==    by 0x4AE4834: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==386==    by 0x4ACBAF1: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1373)
==386==    by 0x4B830EA: __printf_chk (printf_chk.c:33)
==386==    by 0x10A30C: printf (stdio2.h:107)
==386==    by 0x10A30C: main (methods.cpp:258)
==386==
==386== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==386==    at 0x109D12: cleanChArray(char*, int*, char*, char*, int, int&) (methods.cpp:95)
==386==    by 0x10A3FC: main (methods.cpp:277)
==386==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==386==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==386==    by 0x4AD6E83: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==386==    by 0x4AE704F: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==386==    by 0x4AE60AF: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:745)
==386==    by 0x4AE4834: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1244)
==386==    by 0x4AE4834: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==386==    by 0x4ACBAF1: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1373)
==386==    by 0x4B830EA: __printf_chk (printf_chk.c:33)
==386==    by 0x10A30C: printf (stdio2.h:107)
==386==    by 0x10A30C: main (methods.cpp:258)
==386==
==386== Invalid write of size 1
==386==    at 0x10A4A9: main (methods.cpp:286)
==386==  Address 0xb2b2a9c is 0 bytes after a block of size 44 alloc'd
==386==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==386==    by 0x10A418: main (methods.cpp:283)
==386==
==386== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==386==    at 0x4AE5F5D: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:783)
==386==    by 0x4ADB481: putchar (putchar.c:28)
==386==    by 0x10A4B4: printf (stdio2.h:107)
==386==    by 0x10A4B4: main (methods.cpp:287)
==386==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==386==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==386==    by 0x10A343: main (methods.cpp:259)
==386==
==386== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==386==    at 0x4B631E7: write (write.c:26)
==386==    by 0x4AE400C: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1181)
==386==    by 0x4AE5AD0: new_do_write (fileops.c:449)
==386==    by 0x4AE5AD0: _IO_new_do_write (fileops.c:426)
==386==    by 0x4AE5AD0: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:423)
==386==    by 0x4AE6012: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:784)
==386==    by 0x4ADB481: putchar (putchar.c:28)
==386==    by 0x10A4C0: printf (stdio2.h:107)
==386==    by 0x10A4C0: main (methods.cpp:289)
==386==  Address 0x4dc530d is 189 bytes inside a block of size 1,024 alloc'd
==386==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==386==    by 0x4AD6E83: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==386==    by 0x4AE704F: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==386==    by 0x4AE60AF: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:745)
==386==    by 0x4AE4834: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1244)
==386==    by 0x4AE4834: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==386==    by 0x4ACBAF1: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1373)
==386==    by 0x4B830EA: __printf_chk (printf_chk.c:33)
==386==    by 0x10A30C: printf (stdio2.h:107)
==386==    by 0x10A30C: main (methods.cpp:258)
==386==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==386==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==386==    by 0x10A343: main (methods.cpp:259)
==386==
boobyboostboothbootyboozybroodbrookbroombrothchockchoirchordcrockcrookcrosscroupcrowddroitdroopdrossfjordfrockfrostfrothghostgoodygoofygroomgrossgroupgroutivorykioskkioskhobbhowddrooproomrgourorcommhoisgoosfoot
--386-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 7 (SIGBUS) - exiting
--386-- si_code=128;  Faulting address: 0x0;  sp: 0x1008ca9e40

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal

host stacktrace:
==386==    at 0x5805160F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==386==    by 0x58005EB7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==386==    by 0x580A7204: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==386==    by 0x580F5FD4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 386)
==386==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==386==    by 0x10A532: main (methods.cpp:294)
client stack range: [0x1FFEFFC000 0x1FFF000FFF] client SP: 0x1FFEFFDE70
valgrind stack range: [0x1008BAA000 0x1008CA9FFF] top usage: 9480 of 1048576


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

Note: There are various little printf statements and the like that I have tried to use as diagnostic tools. I apologize for the likely illegible appearance of my code. Any and all feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `methods.cpp:75` is the format `<filename>:<lineNumber>` ,, valgrind is flagging line 75 in the file methods.cpp (and similar for the others). .. or did you know that already?

Comment: @yano I did assume that, however, I failed to understand what was wrong with that line of code

Comment: well.. is the code dump in your post methods.cpp? It would at least be helpful to indicate where the line numbers are that valgrind is complaining about. Also note that a wholesale code dump is generally frowned upon for SO, a [mre] is preferred.

Comment: looks like valgrind is saying the line `if(guess_ch == remainingChArray[i+k])` in `cleanChArray` is accessing `remainingChArray` out of bounds. You can put a conditional breakpoint there to break if `i+k` is greater than what you expect the max to be, or add debugging code to print out the sum of `i+k` there to see how high it gets.